# How to make this a simpler code (Java, simple String input, say if it's the correct one or no)

Tags: java

This is hat I've came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String pass = "admin";
    int derp = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Insert the admin pass: ");
    String test = input.nextLine();
    if (pass.equals(test)){
        System.out.print("Access granted");
    }else{
        int counter = 3;
        while (counter > 1){
            counter--;
            System.out.print("You have "+counter+" try(es): ");
            test = input.nextLine();
            if (pass.equals(test)){
                System.out.print("Access granted");
                counter -= 2;
            }else{
                derp++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (derp == 2){
        System.out.print("Access denied");
    }
}
```

How can I make it say "Access denied"? You can probably see that to solve it I just made an int called "derp" What should I do to remove it and still say "Access denied" if the user fails three times?

Thanks. Also, if you think that there are more things that could be improved, I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to introduce any flag to take the decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with below code :

```
            boolean flag = true;
            int counter = 3;
            while(flag)
            {
                if (pass.equals(test))
                {
                    System.out.print("Access granted");
                    break;  // Permission granted so out of the Loop
                }
                else if(counter==0)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }

                System.out.print("You have "+counter+" try(es): ");
                test = input.nextLine();
                counter--;
            }

            if(!flag)
            {
                System.out.print("Access denied");
            }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. But I don't understand why "flag" is the condition for while. I understand that while must have a condition, but is it only there for that? To be a condition so it runs?

Comment: Flag do two thing in the solution.First make the while condition true second to print access denied message  check

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like

```
boolean success = false;
int times = 0;
do {
   input.nextLine();
   if (condition) {
     success = true;
   } else {
     count++;
   }
} while(!success && times < MAX_TIMES);
if (success) {
  print("SUCCESS!!");
} else {
  print("FAIL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   String pass = "admin";
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    System.out.print("Insert the admin pass: ");
    String test = input.nextLine();
    if (pass.equals(test))
    {
     System.out.print("Access granted");
     i=3;
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("Incorrect password, you have "+(2-i)+" attempts remaining");
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop and `break` statement you can do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pass = "admin";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Insert the admin pass: ");
    String test = input.nextLine();
    if (pass.equals(test)) {
        System.out.print("Access granted");
    } else {

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("You have " + i + " try(es): ");
            test = input.nextLine();
            if (pass.equals(test)) {
                System.out.print("Access granted");
                break;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                System.out.print("Access denied");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The attempt count must decrease like 3..2..1...End so change the for condition

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pass = "admin";
    int maxTry = 3;
    boolean success = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Insert the admin pass: ");
    String test = input.nextLine();
    while(maxTry>0){
        maxTry--;
        if (!pass.equals(test)) {
            System.out.print("You have " + maxTry + " try(es): ");
            test = input.nextLine();
        } else {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(success){
        System.out.println("Access granted");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Access denied");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were to write this code, I would have written like following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccessPoint
{
  private Scanner scanner;

  public AccessPoint()
  {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (tryAccessForTimes(3))
    {
      allowAccess();
    }
    else
    {
      denyAccess();
    }

    scanner.close();
  }

  private boolean tryAccessForTimes(int times)
  {
    boolean accessAllowed = false;

    for (int tryIndex = 1; tryIndex <= times && !accessAllowed; tryIndex++)
    {
      if (getAdminPassword().equals(getUserPassword()))
      {
        accessAllowed = true;
      }
      else
      {
        printNumberOfTriesLeft(times, tryIndex);
      }
    }

    return accessAllowed;
  }

  private void printNumberOfTriesLeft(int times, int tryIndex)
  {
    int triesLeft = times - tryIndex;

    if (triesLeft != 0)
    {
      System.out.println("You have " + triesLeft
          + (triesLeft == 1 ? " try" : " tries") + " left.");
    }
  }

  private String getUserPassword()
  {
    System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
    String password = scanner.nextLine();

    return password;
  }

  private String getAdminPassword()
  {
    return "admin";
  }

  private void allowAccess()
  {
    System.out.println("Access Granted.");
  }

  private void denyAccess()
  {
    System.out.println("Access Denied.");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new AccessPoint();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's way too complicated. And I don't understand. But thanks for the time